# what does testing an "stream >> char" do?

Tags: c++, fstream

I have this snippet of code, which has the purpose of defining the >> operator for a struct point (it's not the whole function, just the beginning).

```
struct Point {
    int x; 
    int y;
};
```

The code snippet

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Cord::Point& p) {
        char ch1;
        if (is >> ch1 && ch1 != '(') { // Is this not a point?
            is.unget();
            is.clear(ios_base::failbit);
            return is;
        }
        //More code...
}
```

should function by checking if the input if the first character is ( essentially checking if it should proceed in assuming this point is the form of (x, y). I understand what the 
`ch1 == '('` is doing but what is the purpose of `is  >> ch1`. It must be a boolean, but it seems to always be false because this check always fails from my testing.

Comment: It reads one character from the input. You never encountered `char c; std::cin >> c;`? `It must be a boolean` Yes, `istream` is [convertible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) to `bool`. @edit `istream::opertor bool` returns false if there is an [error](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) with associated stream. Didn't you mean to `if (! is >> ch1 || ch != '(')` ?

Comment: I have. But why is it placed in this if statement and why is it causing it to fail?

Comment: The input routine is brittle. If requires the first character of the line to be a `'('`. That means if there is any leading whitespace (or any character other than `'('`) your check will fail. Further, you are setting `failbit` on the stream. If you are not clearing again before your next read, it will fail as well. Note also that `unget()` clears `eofbit` which could be problematic as well. [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) needed.

Comment: I see. This is really helpful. What would you recommend instead?

Answer (score 0):

> what does testing an “stream >> char” [`is >> ch1`] do?

`>>` is the stream extraction operator. Given a character operand, it extracts a single character from the stream, and assuming no error occurs, assigns the value to the operand.

> It must be a boolean

The stream extraction operator returns the stream. The stream converts implicitly to `bool`. The converted value is true if the stream has no errors and is ready for I/O operations and false otherwise.

Comment: But let's say I enter a '}' character. I should fall into the if statement because it's not '(' but I always seem to skip the statement implying that is >> ch1 is false.

Comment: @AviouslyAK That depends on the state of the stream. If it is in a bad state, then it won't go into the branch because `is >> ch1` would be false.

Comment: [Documentation page for the "The stream converts implicitly to bool" voodoo.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)

Comment: Ahh, I see. I realized I was hitting the error when the state got set to EOF and I had no handling if it was EOF setting the state to bad.